# R paste: ignore sep if argument is an empty string

Tags: r

I'm trying to `paste` together lines of addresses to a single address string. However, some lines are blank (`""`) and this means that an extra `sep` gets inserted and makes the address look ugly. For example:

```
addr.df <- data.frame(street1=c("22B","Windsor Castle"),street2=c("Baker Street",""),city=c("London","Windsor"))

with(addr.df,paste(street1,street2,city,sep=", "))
[1] "22B, Baker Street, London" "Windsor Castle, , Windsor"
```

Notice the extra `,` in the second address. Is there a way round this that doesn't involve a period of regexp induced tourettes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid a little bit of regex-ing.

```
gsub('(, )+',', ',with(addr.df,paste(street1,street2,city,sep=", ")))
```

(the regex says: replace more than one "comma space" with a single "comma space")

Comment: Thanks Justin. The regex wasn't as complicated as I expected, nor did it add as much to the computation time as I expected.

Comment: glad to help.  and I feel your regex pain!

Comment: Great ! This doesn't work if `street1` is empty though, the string will start with a "comma space"

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in one line, with no regexing, but you need to introduce looping (via apply, in this case).

```
apply(
  addr.df, 
  1, 
  function(row) paste(row[nzchar(row)], collapse = ", ")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `nzchar`. Looks quite good, but the answer I accepted was a bit easier to fit into the extended problem.

Comment: Fantastic - this works even if the first string/column is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
streets <- ifelse(street2=="",street1,paste(street1,street2,sep=", "))
```

Then just use `streets` instead of `street1` and `street2` in your whole data-frame paste.

Comment: Thanks, but the actual problem has a larger number of address fields and this construct can become a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the regex and use some simple "if" conditions to check for the number of elements in your data frame.

Hold that for a moment:  do you really want the output to be
 `22B, Baker, London`  as opposed to  `22B Baker, London` (no comma between number and street)?  Assuming that the latter is the desired format,  just do
 `allstreet<-paste(street1,street2,sep=" ")`

And then run your `with` line on `allstreet`  and `city` .
There's probably a much slicker way to do this with `plyr` or `melt` :-)

Comment: Thanks, but the actual problem has a larger number of address fields and this construct can become a bit unwieldy.